# Haskell sum a list with testcase

Tags: list, function, haskell

So I have the following code:

```
data List = Empty | Cons Integer List deriving Show

list = Cons 1 (Cons 7 (Cons 9 (Cons 3 Empty)))
```

Now I want to sum up the list created from above with this function:

```
-- sumList

sumList :: List -> Integer

sumList = sum
```

I do also have a testcase:

```
testSum = putStrLn ("expected: 20\ncomputed: " ++ show (sumList list))
```

My problem is, that I get the following error message:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘List’ with ‘t0 Integer’
  Expected type: List -> Integer
    Actual type: t0 Integer -> Integer
• In the expression: sum
  In an equation for ‘sumList’: sumList = sum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```hs
data List = Empty | Cons Integer List deriving Show

sumList :: List -> Integer
sumList Empty = 0
sumList (Cons x xs) = x + sumList xs
```

As you can see, since `List` is a recursive data type, meaning it can hold instances of itself, we need to recursively open the members and add them all together.

As a test:

```
λ> list = Cons 1 (Cons 7 (Cons 9 (Cons 3 Empty)))
λ> sumList list
20
```

In your code, you are using `sum` from `Data.Foldable`. `sum` has the following signature:

```
λ> :t sum
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
```

This means that it needs a data type with an instance of the `Foldable` class to be able to work on, which `List` obviously does not have.